# How to update or insert variable field in meteor

Tags: meteor

In the updates/insert/query; i want to specify a value of a variable as a key to my query. So in this case i ideally want : `Messages.insert({a: "Hello world");` and  `Messages.update({_id:"aaaaaaaa"},{a: "Hello world");`

For

```
var field = "a";

Messages.insert({field: "Hello world");
Messages.update({_id:"aaaaaaaa"},{field: "Hello world");
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the mongodb [$set](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) modifier:

```
var field = "a";
var secondfield = "b";
Messages.insert({field: field});
Messages.update({_id:"theid"},{$set: {field: secondfield}});
```

Comment: WHY ! Do you get an error message what happens? Can you paste the exact same code you tried?

Comment: DATABASE IS UPDATED WITH : {field: "a"} .. I want {a: "Some value"} ...i want field name to be replaced, values are working fine..  please see my question

Comment: first of all i am getting the following exception `Error: When replacing document, field name may not start with '$'`   `update failed: MongoError: Modifiers and non-modifiers cannot be mixed ` which says that it cannot contain a $. Also the stacktrace :   `Exception while simulating the effect of invoking '/todos/update' 
Error {stack: "Error: When replacing document, field name may not…s?890646cee0821dab27cb869224d31a0f18e3d952:20:15)"}
 Error: When replacing document, field name may not start with '$'`

Comment: Can you paste the exact code you are using or I cannot help you.

Comment: CLIENT SIDE :: $meteor("todos").update({_id: todo._id},
                {$set:{field: "replaecr"}}
            );   AND ON SERVER --> 197505 {"msg":"method","method":"/todos/update","params":[{"_id":"wFKoMpDBHfwrXW9oj"},{"$set":{"$set":{"field":"replaecr"}}}],"id":"2"}
<-- 3 {"msg":"updated","methods":["2"]}
<-- 6 {"msg":"result","id":"2","error":{"error":409,"reason":"MongoError: Modified field name may not start with $","message":"MongoError: Modified field name may not start with $ [409]","errorType":"Meteor.Error"}}

Comment: On the server you are using $set twice in the same query?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var field = "a";
Messages.insert({field: field});
```

This should give you a document like:

```
{ _id: "<the_id">,
  field: "a"
}
```

Then you can update the fields

```
var fields = {};

fields["a"] = "b";
fields["secondfield"] = "c";

Messages.update({_id:"<the_id>"},{$set: fields});
```

This should get you a document that looks like :

```
{ "_id": "<the_id">,
  "field": "a",
  "a":"b",
  "secondfield":"c"
}
```

Not sure exactly what you want to do but you can do all sorts of updates by just modifying `fields["<field name>"] = "<value">` & using the `$set` operator to update them.

Comment: AWESOME,, WORKS,, i love you Tarang !